# Script to automatic connect to a ssh cluster

Tags: ssh

For numerical calculus, I'm using a cluster. It's located in the college network, so if I want to use it from my house, I need to ssh to the college network (using a account we can use), and then connect from there to the cluster.

The college network allows 2 attempts to connect; if both fail, then the user is banned and must contact to the administrator.  User name and password are easy to forget or mistype, so this happens frequently.

My knowledge of coding is restricted to Fortran and some basic Linux commands. How can I automatically connect to a network, authenticate in it and then connect to the other network?

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a solution for you problem, If your college network allow you to authenticate using `private-public key` that would be a prefect solution for your problem, but that solve only the first part of your problem, for automatic connect to the cluster, I think without `NAT` that would be difficult, but you can do the same thing between the collage network and the cluster